# Reduce List Objects field in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, reduce

I have model, return and list below:

```java
public class Occurrence {
       private Integer id;
       private String description;
       private String status;
      // gets/sets
}

List<Occurrence> list = this.getOccurrences();
```

My function returns:

```java
[ {"id": 1, "description": "One", "status": "Initial"},{"id": 1, "description": "One", "status": "Doing"}, {"id": 1, "description": "One", "status": "Almost"}, {"id": 1, "description": "One", "status": "Done!!"} ]
```

How can I reduce the values list to this?:

```java
["id": 1, "description": "One", "status": ["Initial", "Doing", "Almost", "Done!!"] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create another object that represents an Occurance but with multiple statuses. The issue is that you're trying to group multiple statuses into one but an Occurance only supports a single status.

```java
    public static final class MultiStatusOccurrence {

        private final int id;

        private final List<String> statuses;

        public MultiStatusOccurrence(int id, List<String> statuses) {
            this.id = id;
            this.statuses = statuses;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public List<String> getStatuses() {
            return statuses;
        }
    }
```

Then you need to map the occurrences together if they have the same ID (assuming it's unique) and group the statuses. This assumes the description can be dropped since it's not unique and is the same throughout.

```java
        List<Occurrence> occurrences = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new Occurrence(1, "Hello World!", "Done!"),
                new Occurrence(1, "Hello World!", "Done2!")));

        List<MultiStatusOccurrence> multiStatusOccurrences = occurrences.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Occurrence::getId))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(entry -> new MultiStatusOccurrence(entry.getKey(), 
                        entry.getValue().stream()
                                .map(Occurrence::getStatus)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```